# Load oracle Dataframe in dask dataframe

Tags: python, error-handling, dask

I used to work with pandas and cx_Oracle until now. But I haver to switch to dask now due to RAM limitations.

```
import pandas as pd
from dask import dataframe as dd
import os
import cx_Oracle as cx


con = cx.connect('USER','userpw' , 'oracle_db',encoding='utf-8') 
cursor = con.cursor()

query_V_Branchen = ('''SELECT * FROM DBOWNER.V_BRANCHEN vb''')

daskdf = dd.read_sql_table(query_V_Branchen,con ,index_col= 'RECID')
```

I tried to do it similar to how I used cx_oracle with pandas. But I receive an AttributeError named:

```
'cx_Oracle.Connection' object has no attribute '_instantiate_plugins'
```

Any ideas if its just a problem with the package?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please read the [dask doc on SQL](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/dataframe-sql.html):

- you should provide a [connection string](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/engines.html#oracle), not an object
- you should give a table name, not a query, or phrase your query using sqlalchemy's expression syntax.

e.g.,

```
df = dd.read_sql_table('DBOWNER.V_BRANCHEN', 
    'oracle+cx_oracle://USER:userpw@oracle_db', index_col= 'RECID')
```